# Should barleywine be carbonated?

Tags: barleywine, carbonation

I've was introduced to barleywine this past weekend, and I was interested.  So I start googling, and find that Northern Brewer has a kit that comes with carbonation.  The barleywine I had was uncarbonated.  Most of the recipes that I googled didn't say one way or the other.

Should barleywine be carbonated, or should I bottle it still?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the BJCP, both English and American styles of barleywine should have low to moderate levels of carbonation, depending on age and conditioning.

[BJCP Category 19](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style19.php)

Of course, it's your beer, drink it you would like, but that's what the style guide says and most if not all commercial examples of barleywine are carbonated.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a barley wine that was not carbonated. But at the same time if you prefer it uncarbonated, don't carbonate it then. This seems more like a question to be left to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be carbonated.